# How to make excel treat text as string in Clojure using data.csv?

Tags: excel, csv, clojure

I am using data.csv to write export data to a csv while however i have some alphanumeric fields which are ids but since they are all numbers excel is treating them is doubles and showing them in exponential form.

Is there a way that we can tell excel to treat is as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Excel displays long numbers in csv files in an abbreviated form with exponents.
Unfortunately there is no way to disable that functionality from within the generated csv.
Also sending it in as text shows the same abbreviated format. Your choices are

1) Assuming the id number has fewer than 16 digits you can go into excel and change the format.

2) Alternatively you can prepend an apostrophe or text character to your id's before you generate the csv. For example

```
(ns sample.core
  (:use [clojure.data.csv]
        [clojure.java.io]))


(defn gen-csv [filename]
  (with-open [out-file (writer filename)]
    (write-csv out-file
                 [["'123000000" "'45612333"]
                  ["'789909990" "'90099999124"]])))
```